# Memory management of imported modules in Python

Tags: python, memory-management, module

I have some doubts with Memory management of imported modules in Python.

1 .where memory will be allocated for python's modules
2. is memory allocation deleted from the memory and when it is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** In *python*, memory for a module is allocated during program execution. When you import a module into your program, the *Python interpreter* parses the module's code and allocates memory for all objects, functions, variables, and other elements defined in it.

**2.** Memory allocation for objects in *Python* is managed by an automatic garbage collection mechanism ***(garbage collector)***, which frees the memory occupied by objects when they are no longer in use.

When are they no longer used? - When there are no variables that refer to them

> The important thing is that you can delete an item without the help of
> the **Garbage Collector** through methods such as *'del'* and *'gc.collect()'*
> from the *'gc'* module to speed up the program if you work with large
> amounts of data. But usually, the work of the **Garbage Collector** is
> enough. In languages such as *C* and *C++*, there is no such garbage
> collector, so you have to do everything manually.